# Why isn't my KeyListener working?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

This is my code.

Essentially, I create a `player` object that manipulates the animation; however the `GameController` sends the `Player` commands through public static methods.

However, I'm having trouble with that part since my `keyPressed`, `keyReleased`, and `keyTyped` aren't working.

I put in print statements to check if the `KeyEvent` would show anything but it didn't. I also checked my code with a `mouseListener` which worked. Thus, I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import objectdraw.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class GameController extends WindowController implements KeyListener, MouseListener {

   Player player;

   public GameController() {

      super();

   }

   public void begin() {

      Image sprite0 = getImage("1.png"); 
      canvas.addKeyListener(this);
      canvas.addMouseListener(this);
      player = new Player (250, 0, sprite0 ,canvas);

   }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

      System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());

   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

      System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());

   }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

   }

   public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) { }
   public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) { }
   public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {

      if (Player.canJump && !Player.falling) {

         Player.canJump = false;
         Player.falling = false;
         Player.jumping = true;

      }

   }

   public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e ) { }
   public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
   }   

}
```

Comment: Is `begin()` getting called?

Comment: There are many things missed in your question, provide them to get better help and soon answer: 1) Where is the frame  2) `canvas` is a frame or panel?  3) What's `WindowController` ?

Comment: Yes the begin is being called. The image is properly displayed, so I'm assuming its being called.

A  WindowController is used with objectdraw. Basically, it creates a "DrawingCanvas" for me and I run the appletviewer like appletviewer controler.html

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Tip:  Add @JohnFoley (or whoever, the @ is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.

Comment: Instead of "public void begin()",
try just "public begin()".

Comment: I fail to see how that will actually compile

Comment: ohhh. never mind, I thought begin() was the default constructor.

Comment: @Steven : Now since you know, that this answer of yours is providing nothing good to the community, why not delete it then ? Or you can improve on your last answer. At least donot keep it as it is and attract more down votes :-)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely issue is that the component you are registering your key listener to is either not focusable or doesn't have focus.

A key listener can only be notified of events if the component it is register actually has key board focus (and can receive key board focus).

Instead, use the [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API

Answer (score 2):

It seems your component is not focusable. To use `KeyListener` has to be focusable and has to be in focus.

Instead you can use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) Bind for a key an specific action.

Simple Example:

```
AbstractAction escapeAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //code here example
         ((JComponent)e.getSource()).setVisible(Boolean.FALSE);
    }};
 String key = "ESCAPE";
 KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);
 component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, key);
 component.getActionMap().put(key, escapeAction);
```

You can use these JComponent constants

> ```
> WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT 
> WHEN_FOCUSED 
> WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
> ```

Also check about [Single Responsability Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) it seems that your gameController is too much things, is a `MouseListener` `KeyListener` and also a `WindowController`. Instead of that think about if is not better has a private class inside your class for example

```
public class GameController extends WindowController{

  private class MyMouselistener implements MouseListener{
          //code here
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out :)

Comment: Considering accepting an answer as correct and upvoting all who help you